# how to embed yt video on the site without navigation bar (play pause etc)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I need to embed video on my site. Div which holds that has got 152/107 px. That why I would like to make navigation bar (play, stop, pause) bottom strip invisible.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Add **controls=0** to video url.
Didn't test it, but reading the API, then it seems to be the right thing.

Also, here is a link for all the youtube player parameters (autoplay, allow fullscreen etc..)
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

**NOTE** If you wish to have truly custom player. Then maybe [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) is your best choice..

Comment: I added "&controls=0" to end of embedded iframe src url. It worked! Note that if this is the only parameter added to the url it should instead be "?controls=0".

Answer (score 0):

why not use the new iframe player by youtube? the navigation bar hides when you move away with the mouse from it